# Performance of Graphviz

Tags: c++, performance, graphviz

How fast is Graphiz? I want to implement a profiler which keeps track of threads state. I want to build and visualize waits-for graphs in real time (!).

Is this even possible? Would Graphviz be the appropriate match?

Otherwise, are there alternative for C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use Graphviz because it is designed for creating graphical visualization of graph structures. Instead, might I suggest using the [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html)? While I have not used it personally, the Boost libraries are well respected, and it seems to be everywhere when I try to look for graphs in c++. I think that you will find the boost implementation will meet your needs.

Comment: Sorry I misformulated my question, I want to visualize graphs!

Comment: I agree, the Boost Graph Library is the better option. It has very little overhead. And it does also have input/output functions for Graphviz and GraphML if you want to save your graphs (or snap-shots of your profiling results) and later visualize them with standard tools. I would not recommend trying to do both the visualization and profiling at the same time, I would imagine that any code that does that would be quite slow (unless your program only has a few threads).

Comment: I guess the best approach would be to sample all changes to the graph and reconstruct waits-for graphs at the end of profiling at a snapshot of the program.